# Does PostgreSQL version 11.8 support import of database created in PostgreSQL version 8.4.20?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm un running PostgreSQL version 11.8 in Windows Server 2016, and in PostgreSQL shell, I'm trying to import a dump database file that was exported using PostgreSQL version 8.4.20. However, get error as "database ... does not exist"
Using Windows Dos command prompt, tried:

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin> pg_dump -U postgres C:\folderName\databaseName.dump > C:\AnotherFolderName\databasenew.sql
```

However, get an error as:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db) connection to database C:\folderName\databaseName.dump" failed: FATAL "C:\folderName\databaseName.dump" does not exist
```

Also, I tried removing the .dump extension as follows:

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin> pg_dump -U postgres C:\folderName\databaseName > C:\AnotherFolderName\databasenew2.sql
```

and get error, too:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db) connection to database C:\folderName\databaseName" failed: FATAL "C:\folderName\databaseName" does not exist
```

Comment: You need to specify the name of a database, not a folder name for `pg_dump` (or any Postgres command line tool) To get a list of available database names use `psql -l`. To "import" a SQL ("plain text") dump, you need to use `psql -d database_name -f databasenew2.sql` see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) for details

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name .  The .dump database was obtained from a different environment.  I'm my Windows 2016 server, I  saved such dump file into the an attached drive. I thought in Windows, I had to go c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin and specify the folder location of the dump file. Thank you.

Comment: Are you loking for: ```pg_restore -f C:\AnotherFolderName\databasenew.sql C:\folderName\databaseName.dump```? This will only work if ```C:\folderName\databaseName.dump``` was created using a custom format. If the dump file is a text file you will need to use ```psql```.

Comment: You need to *connect*  to an existing database (which is not the same as a folder). Once you can do that, you can run `psql -d database_name -f databasenew2.sql` to import the dump. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) for details

Comment: Thank you folks.  I received .dump the file compressed  in .gz format. In WindowsServer 2016, I unzipped and resulted C:\FolderName\databaseName.dump. Then, launched PgAdmin and created a database called 'databasenew'. In Windows CMD shell, ran         
 `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin> psql -U postgres`  Next,  entered password for postgres. In postgres=#, ran `psql -d databaseName.dump  -f databasenew.sql` . Then, returns to `postgres=# ` prompt. PgAdmin UI does not show the "databasenew"

Answer (score 1):

You need to *restore* your dump file, so you should feed it to `pg_restore`.

While `pg_restore` will do its best to read and interpret the 8.4 dump properly, the recommended practice is to dump the 8.4 database with `pg_dump` from v11.

Comment: Note Larenz Albe.  Thank you for your advice.